# How to test is a string is initialized in c?

Tags: c, string, initialization

Quick and easy C question: `char* foo`

How can I test if `foo` hasn't still been assigned a value?

Thanks.

Comment: If you write `char* foo;`, then `foo` is __defined__. You want to know whether it is __initialized__.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't.

Instead, initialize it with `NULL` and check whether it is `NULL`:

```
char *foo = NULL;
...
if(!foo) { /* shorter way of saying if(foo == NULL) */
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't test at runtime in a platform-independent way. Doing anything with an uninitialized value other than assigning to it is undefined behaviour. Look at the source and analyse the code flow.

It may be that your compiler initialises stack memory with a particular value, and you could test for this value. It's not portable even to the same compiler with different flags (because the standard doesn't require it, and it might only happen in debug mode), and it's not reliable because you might have assigned the "magic" value.

What you'd normally do in this case is initialize the pointer to `NULL` (equivalently, 0), then later test whether it is `NULL`. This doesn't tell you whether you've assigned NULL to it or not in the intervening time, but it tells you whether you've assigned a "useful" value.

Comment: If it's a global, it would be initialized.

Comment: @Carl: true, although it's still not possible to test whether it has been assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is defined/declared just not initialized. You can check if your variable has a value by first initializing it when you declare it.  Then later you can check if it has that initial value.

```
char *foo = NULL;


//...

if(foo)
{
}
```